# Get text from WP7 ClipBoard

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hi I'm creating the MaskedTextBox. I want to get the text form Clip board. if i'm using Clipboard.gettext(), throwing **SecurityException**. Is there any way to get the text from Clipboard in WP7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597033%28v=VS.96%29.aspx):

> "You cannot get clipboard text from a Windows Phone application, only
>   set it. Calling the GetText method in a Windows Phone application will
>   always cause a SecurityException to occur."

Libraries like http://wp7clipboard.codeplex.com/ are a bit of a hack, you will *never* be able to pick up the clipboard text that someone enters from the email application for example.

Comment: wp7clipboard is a *lot* of a hack. not just a "bit"! ;)

Comment: @MattLacey it is, but hacking is a lot of fun :-P